# How to Prevent user entries in Bot Chat text window C#

Tags: c#, azure, bots

[I want to Prevent user entries while chat bot asks question to user with Yes/No, user should be select only Yes/No buttons, chat should not allow for any text this time. How to do this.

Please find the below image.

[image]

Comment: Hi, what did you try? Do you have any code? Your requirement might be acomplished just with a simple "if" or with the more complex and beatiful solution.

Comment: I don't have any code for disable/prevent that marked control from user entries. Can you please help me on this.